# This vba refrence is not working

Tags: excel, vba, macros

This cell reference is not giving me values.

```
For i = 0 To lastrow
   For j = 0 To lastcolmn
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(87 + j, 4 + i).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(6 + j, 1 + i).Value
Next j
Next i
```

Comment: please find the time to respond and give feedback to previous posts you had here (you gave 0 answers from 18 posts !)

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: What are the values of `lastrow` and `lastcoumn` when the failure occurred??

Answer (score 0):

Apart from anything else `Cells` refers to Rows then Columns, eg.

`Cells(row,column)`